# Find Debian service or daemon based on output text

Tags: bash, debian-based

Someone implemented a poorly designed service or daemon on a Debian production machine.
It is sporadically killing a background worker when it thinks RAM usage is too high with `kill -15`
However, it keeps firing without justification.
Let's assume the output text is "Running kill block -15".
How can I locate the service/daemon on Debian running this and disable it?

I used `find` with a `grep` for locating the text, nothing returned so far.
I also browsed into init.d to check for the existence of this text.
Nothing...

Comment: Try using the `strings` command to extract text from binary files, then grep the result of that. Keep in mind that the program may build the string dynamically, so you may not see the entire string in a single line.

Comment: @MosheKatz: thank you for this suggestion. I however need to search recursively, so something like `find / -type f | xargs strings | grep 'kill'`, what do you think of this?

Comment: I would probably start with a slightly larger string than just "kill" - that one will probably get you far too many results. Other than that, it looks like about what I would do.

Comment: If the service is continuously running, you could start by looking (with `ps`)  at all the binaries which are running nun.